# Get MIME type from RESTful API Call

Tags: document-library, rest, file

I am currently using Sharepoint 2013 and am using this URI to get some basic metadata about the documents under the document directory:
`/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Modified,FileSystemObjectType,GUID`.

What I am looking for is to additionally get the MIME type or application type of a file though this call. I would think that simply adding another field such as `FileType` would suffice, but it doesn't seem so. Is there a way to get this information from this call?

If the MIME type cannot be retrieved from this call, is there a separate call I can make to get such information?

Comment: Note that SharePoint doesn't store any information about the MIME type of files, it's added by IIS during the request for a specific resource, mapped by file extension.

Comment: Thank you, @JamesLove. Do you know of a field that I can add to my URI that just returns the file extension?

Comment: Try `DocIcon` - it returns the extension to be used to shown the icon of the doc.

Answer (score 1):

To determine file type you could add `File_x0020_Type` or `DocIcon` to the list of selected properties, for example:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items?$select=File_x0020_Type
```